# Access "parents" class members

Tags: c++, class

I've learned that using a global variable is not good practice, and I don't want to use a static variable, since it behaves like a "global" variable as well, if I'm correct.

In the code below I want class B to get access to its "parents" member, is that possible? (see class B constructor).

Or how should I approach this, where I want to access var/members between classes?

Friends, seems not to be the way either.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    int number_I_want = 987;
    A() {
        B* classB = new B();
    }
};

class B {
public:
    int nr = 0;
    B() {
        nr = this->parent->number_I_want; /// Here I want to access the "parent" A's member with value 987 
        cout << nr * nr;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* classA = new A();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Data members has to be private, or else what would be the use of OOP?

Comment: @Xenikh You make them private when there's a need for that, otherwise it turns into cargo-cult OOP.

Comment: @MikaelSvensson I don't see inheritance in the code. `A` and `B` are two unrelated classes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but won't it go against the properties of encapsulation?

Comment: @Xenikh Encapsulation is just a tool, you may not need it depending on what kind of class you're writing. E.g. if you end up writing a minimal getter&setter for your field, and are certain that they'll always stay this way, you might as well make the field public.

Comment: (edit) You got something confused here. Global variables should not be used because they're accessible from anywhere and they pollute the global namespace. That's precisely why static variables are a thing - so that you can make a global variable without these disadvantages. Anyway, what you're asking makes no sense. You can create an instance of B manually without ever using A. What's stopping you from defining a B::B(int)?

Comment: You seem to have some basic misunderstandings on how things work. In your code, an instance of class `A` creates an instance of class `B` on the heap and temporarily knows it's address. It forgets this address after the constructor and produces a memory leak. In any case, the instance of `B` exists independently of `A`, and knows nothing of it. What you could do, of course, is to give the instance of `B` a pointer to the instance of `A`.

Comment: (to follow on from @Aziuth) . .but usually you want to follow the 'law of demeter' and only pass in what the class actually needs, in this case an integer. This helps reduce unnecessary coupling and makes it easier to unit test your code.

Comment: Thanx for your replies! So it was like I thought, but didn't hope for then that you couldn't access members betweeen classes. I have to think of another way of doing this. What I want is a "main" class that holds the members used in many classes, but that is maybe just the wrong way to think..

Comment: Not at all. You can totally do that, and this is basically the concept of ownership. A classic tree-like hierachy. Maybe you should get yourself some library that uses a similar concept and see how that one did it. For example, a widget in Qt is pretty much always a child of another widget, owned by it, deleted when the parent is deleted, and knows a pointer to it's parent. Or another thing you can do, simply read into tutorials on basic data structures. Most do not have parent pointers, but some do.

Comment: In any case, try out stuff. You will make mistakes, that is fine. Try out some pattern, see if it works for you, and see if it will cause any avoidable trouble.

Comment: I posted an answer that worked for me, if your interested..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pointer to >>this<< keyword when creating a "child" class worked for me.

```
class A {
public:
    int nr;
    A();
};

class B {
public:
    B(A* classA) {
        std::cout << "Written in class B, value from class A: "<< classA->nr;
    };
};

A::A() {
    nr = 77;
    B* classB = new B(this);
    delete classB;
}

int main() {
    A* classA = new A();
    delete classA;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is no parent\child relation for object. Sometimes it gets confusing with people coming from languages with object memory model (which are either VM-based or interpreters). Parent there is an object owning this one. C++ uses abstract memory model. If a class Bis inherited from other class A, class A is abase class of B. Base class and class members are subobjects of given class, meaning their storage is part of enclosing object's storage. Consecutively base class's members are subobjects too and are accessible as class members with consideration of access level and inheritance level (private, public, protected).

Enclosing object owns included ones and call to its destructor results in their destruction.

If you need actual parent\child relation , you have to implement it and pass a pointer (?) to parent into child's constructor, while it have to be able to register self within given parent.

Some C++ framework emulate object model by using metaprogramming technique, e.g. Qt Framework's QObject may have a parent and list of children.

Comment: What I want is a "main" class that has members being used in other classes. But that's just not the way to go at all?

Comment: @MikaelSvensson oh, it might be a little too advanced for starter level. If I understand right you're nearing the idea of Entity-Component-System approach. It can be done but it isn't a language paradigm (LUA language could do that, I recon)

Comment: @MikaelSvensson in simplified terms, you may have either some kind of storage within class, or a global storage to which this class would refer to get those "child" objects. You have to constructs objects by explicitly telling them whom they belong and they add themselves to that storage.

Comment: @MikaelSvensson the consumer object have to have some kind of interface to interact with childrens. E.g. to add or remove a child object. A child would have interface to be added or removed (can there be shared ones? that would require a global storage). In ECS such objects called Entities..in some cases they don't even exist as object but as an id to a list of owned components - children objects. A system would be a separate manager of certain components or entities

Comment: @MikaelSvensson the "main" class would be essentially a System.

Comment: I posted an answer that worked for me, if your interested..

Answer (score 0):

Class A is The parent class so if the members/fields  are not private . you can access them in class B. But the class B must Be the child of class A. You have to extend class b from A. And if you have parametrized constructor of parent class you must initialize classA constructor from class B

Comment: Ckass A is no parent class. The classes are totally unrelated.

Comment: So you have to create a object of class A in Class B in this way you can access instance members of class A @tofro

Comment: If you want to be A a parent class of B you need to derive B from A. That's not done in the example.